# No provider for AngularFirestore when i import AngularFirestoreModule and AngularFireModule inside lazyloaded module

Tags: angularfire2, angularfire5

When I import AngularFireModule and AngularFirestoreModule inside root module of my angular application everything works fine.But don;t want to import them in my root module to keep my root module bundle small.So I import  them inside lazy loaded module which is loaded on demand by the router.In these case i get error NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore! because I have a service where I am using AngularFirestore service. how can I solve this problem?

but  if I do same thing in lazy loaded module it doesn't work